# sum each rows in array 2d python

Tags: python, list, matrix, sum

I try to create 2d array in python which accept input from user to ask how many 2d array to be made. and my program also sum value number in every rows in array 2d and print greatest value per array.

example:

input:

```
2 - for how much array need to create

2 -> for how much size array(rows default = 3)
1 2 3
4 5 6
3
0 0 0
2 3 4
5 6 7
```

output:

```
in array 1 is : 2 (represent row) -> (4+5+6) is greatest than (1+2+3)
in array 2 is : 3 (represent row) -> (5+6+7) is greatest
```

my program stack in how to sum it and print the right output. and also have some problem with some unsupported operand type(s) for +:.maybe anyone wants help me to fixed it. this my code

```
A = int(input("enter how many matrix create: "))
for i in range(A):
    B = int(input("enter size : ")) 
    matrix = []
    print("enter number: ")
    for j in range(B):          
        a =[]
        for k in range(B):
            a.append(input())
        matrix.append(a) 
    rows = len(matrix)
    cols = len(matrix[0])
    total=0
    for r in range(0, rows):
        rowtotal=0
        for s in range(0, cols):
            rowtotal=rowtotal+int(matrix[r][s])
        print(rowtotal)
    total=total+rowtotal
print(total)
```

i need your opinion about this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Unsupported operant type for +" error raised when you tried to add string type and int type or different type and different type.
You can only concatenate the same type

In this part of your code, I did understand the use of rowtotal and total.

```
for r in range(0, rows):
    rowtotal=0
    for s in range(0, cols):
        rowtotal=rowtotal+int(matrix[r][s])
    print(rowtotal)
total=total+rowtotal
```

Here is the sample code I wrote according to your question.

```
# accept the number of martix
a = int(input("Enter how many matrix to create: "))
sizes_of_array = []
largest_rows = []

for i in range(a):      
      b = int(input("\nEnter size: "))
      sizes_of_array.append(b)
      List = []

      # accept input rows
      for j in range(b):
            Input = input('Enter {}th row separated with blank: '.format(j+1))
            temp = Input.split()
            List.append([int(x) for x in temp])

      # print the matrix you wrote
      print('\nYour matrix: ')
      for k in range(b):
            for l in range(b):
                  print(List[k][l],end=' ')
            print()

      # find the row with largest sum value
      largest_sum = max(sum(x) for x in List)
      for x in List:
            if sum(x) == largest_sum:
                  largest_rows.append(x)
                  break

# final results
print('\n')
for i in range(a):
      print('In array {}, there is {} rows and  {}  is the greatest.'.format(i+1,sizes_of_array[i],largest_rows[i]))
```

It accepts inputs according to number of rows; one row per times.
I made to print the whole matrix after the inputs.
Feels free to ask the part of the code you didn't get.