# create more than once 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays

how to make 2d array in python with input from user which user can input how much array 2d needed.
example :

input :

```
2 -> indicates how many arrays you want
2 -> indicate size of array(2 for rows and column set default 3)
2 3 4
5 6 7
3
4 5 6
7 8 9
1 2 3
```

and output: print it all

i try but i can't get right answer in my code. that's my code:

```
A = int(input("enter how many matrix create: "))
for i in range(A):
    B = int(input("enter size : ")) 
    matrix = []
    print("enter number: ")
    for j in range(B):          
        a =[]
        for k in range(3):
            a.append(input())
        matrix.append(a) 
print(matrix)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `2 for rows and columns set default 3`?

Comment: that's means size of 2d array which 2 rows & 3 column, rows can set various according to what the user wants @RoboMop

Comment: Okay, so if the user enters `2 4` in that part, it should be a matrix with 2 rows and 4 columns but if the user enters just `4`, then it should be a matrix with 4 rows and 3 (default) columns right?

Comment: Have you searched for it? What did you get?

Comment: the user only input once (rows) only in part B = int(input("enter size : "))  @RoboMop

Comment: Ohh, understood.

Comment: search for what? @Trilarion

Comment: @rey Search for the solution to your problem. How to create more than once 2d array in python for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```py
print("Enter the number of arrays:")
K = int(input())

# This stores all the arrays
array = []

for i in range(K):
    print("Enter the number of rows and columns you want:")
    rows = int(input())
    columns = 3 # You don't actually need to use this in your code
    matrix = []
    print("Start entering the rows:")
    for j in range(rows):
        matrix.append(input().split())
    array.append(matrix)
```

**Note:** This stores the elements in a string form, so instead of the number 1, it stores `'1'` (as a string)

To convert the input into multiple integers, you can use the `list` and `map` functions like this:

```py
print("Enter the number of arrays:")
K = int(input())

# This stores all the arrays
array = []

for i in range(K):
    print("Enter the number of rows and columns you want:")
    rows = int(input())
    columns = 3 # Because it's the default value
    matrix = []
    print("Start entering the rows:")
    for j in range(rows):
        matrix.append(list(map(int, input().split()))) # Converts the input into a list of integers
    array.append(matrix)
```

Comment: thank's bro. and maybe i need your solution again in my post before it continuation of this question. you can see in my profile. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67837950/15519176

Answer (score 0):

1. You are creating a new list (called `matrix`) at every step of your outer `for` loop - the one starting at line 2 `for i in range(A)`: you want to initialize `matrix` *outside* of the outer loop.
2. You have two inner `for` loops: why? You only need two loops in total (it's a 2d array).